# Unable to create directory error on xammp ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, wordpress

I have installed WordPress with Xampp. Now when i am trying to upload image in wordpress it shows the following errors. `Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2016/08.` Is its parent directory writable by the server? what should i do? Thank You

Comment: I assume you are using windows, I belive the directory wp-content/uploads needs the NTFS permissions changed. See this http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-setting.htm

Comment: Ah okay. Then you will need to use chmod to change the permissions of the directory.

Comment: can you please tell me how? and which directory?

Comment: Do you have access to a terminal? or just FTP

Comment: i am with terminal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43531/discussion-between-smehsan-and-mt025).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the linux ownership of the directory. To do this, you need to know the owner of the httpd/apache process you can get this by typing `ps aux | grep apache` or `ps aux | grep httpd`. Normally the owner is nobody or deamon.

Then `cd` into your wp-content directory. e.g. `cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content` and create the uploads directory `mkdir uploads`.

You will then need to set this directorys owner to the user that is running apache. e.g. `sudo chown deamon uploads`

Try your upload again and it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Try the settings > Media option in wordpress and set the correct media uploads path. Sometimes while changing servers and restoring wordpress from backups the problem occurs. I see that you have fixed the issue. But for other looking for a solutions here is a good 2 step guide.
http://rooturaj.com/technology/unable-to-create-directory-wordpress/